# Google map in android,display in small size mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I want to display location in map view & map size should be 200X200.
I tried loading map in mapview but its not displaying properly after tapping on direction pointer 2 to 3 times its displaying correct map but not moving.

[image: map]

But when I use complete size of screen for displaying map without changing any code it's loading correctly.How can i display same iin small view?

map code-

```
static GoogleMap map;
private MapView mapView;
MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());

        switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()) )
        {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
            if(mapView!=null)
            {
                map = mapView.getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10);
                map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING: 
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SERVICE MISSING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED: 
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UPDATE REQUIRED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(location).zoom(10).bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(70)    // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build();    // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

**Solution -** 
Done using fragment -

map_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reg_office_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tata_auto"
        android:textColor="@color/tatablue"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java code -

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    public  GoogleMap map; 
    private Location location;
    private LatLng mAddress1;
    public static boolean inMap=false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_map, container, false);
        setMapView();
        return view;
    }

    private void setMapView(){
        CurrentLocation mCurrentLoc=new CurrentLocation(getActivity());
        location = CurrentLocation.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) { 
            mCurrentLoc.onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            mCurrentLoc.onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        //class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment)).getMap();


        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(mAddress1).zoom(8).bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(30)    // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build();    // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


    }
}
```

mAddress1 is latitude and longitude of your location.

Comment: having you got solution?

Comment: @LazyCoder I have added solution.check it

Comment: not displaying your solution

Comment: @LazyCoder check my post only Below Solution. I can answer my own question.

Comment: hk great ... cause need somthing like this thanks

Comment: @yuvaツ, You need not use MapFragment compulsorily. Check my answer below.

Comment: @gnuanu But I got solution now.And its working very well..I have used fragment activity in my map now.

Answer (score 8):

I tested the code below and there is no problems with the map to the size 200dp x 200dp

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment
{
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(38.7222524, -9.139336599999979))
                .title("MyLocation")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_mobileedge_navpoint)));

        // Move the camera instantly  with a zoom of 15.
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( new LatLng( 38.7222524, -9.139336599999979), 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 1000, null);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! plz help regarding your solution.. inside Fragment why it is giving an error "validate resource references inside android xml file"  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"     "maps.SupportMapFragment" is marked red ?

Answer (score 8):

**Update - 11 August 2020**

`MapView.getMap()` has been replaced with `MapView.getMapAsync()`

---

I see that you are using MapView instead of MapFragment. In Google Maps V2, the old MapView class `com.google.android.maps.MapView` is obsolete. So make sure you use the correct MapView both in your Java code and XML layout which should be

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
```

and

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="your_width"
    android:layout_height="your_height" />
```

Also make sure you have made all necessary changes in AndroidManifest.xml, which includes defining the API_KEY for Maps V2 [as described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2).

Apart from this, there is a major thing you have to do if you are using MapView in place of a MapFragment, you have to call the MapView's overridden functions explicitly inside the corresponding overrides of residing Activity just like,

```
public class YourMapActivity extends Activity {

    MapView mMapView;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Your OnCreate with Map Initialization */

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mMapView.onCreate(Bundle.EMPTY);

        mMap = mMapView.getMap();
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mMapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

This should be enough for loading a custom sized MapView in your Acitivity. You may also use the following functions to make it suit your requirement.

```
mMapView.setClickable(false);

mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonnabled(false);
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: mapView.getMap() no longer available

Comment: @YashaswiNP Yep, they replaced the function with an Async version. Thanks. Well, the answer is 6 years old :)