# How to show map in smaller android screen size?

Tags: android, google-maps, containers

How can I make my map show only on top half screen on an Android Device? I adeed a fragment, but it shows full  screen. I have done this so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_custom_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="br.com.medicomap.MapContainerActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        android:id="@+id/containerInfo"></LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>[
```

Comment: What you need is marker clustering. Read the doc here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: t has to be one map for each place. It's similar to that apps who shows, for example, a restaurant, say the adress, what kind of food, and bellow is a map showing where it is.

Comment: share ss of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Just added a screen of my desired layout. I can't add a small map on top of fragment.

Comment: You can have map fragment on top half of screen and bottom layout can be dynamic text.. on click of marker you can change the texts at bottom.

Comment: Sourav, when I use map fragment It takes the whole screen and ignores whatever I add below It. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You can assign weight or use percentrelativelayout then it won't consume full screen or set some width http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010051/google-map-in-android-display-in-small-size-mapview

Comment: It worked, Sourav Ganguly, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please mark this as answer so that it can help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign weight or use percentrelativelayout then it won't consume full screen or set some width [Google map in android,display in small size mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010051/google-map-in-android-display-in-small-size-mapview)

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking to use Google Maps app on the device then you can use external links to redirect user to google Maps app with specific location. Use this

https://www.google.com/maps/?q=11.4866901,99.1050785

Where `Latitude` is `11.4866901` and `Longitude` is `99.1050785`.

Comment: Not really what I want. I really need it to open in the app, together with the place adress and info.